# Circular Singly Linked List using Java

Tags: java, linked-list, console, circular-list

Please review my implementation of a Circular Singly Linked List.

```
public class NodeS {

    public int num;
    public NodeS next;

    public NodeS(int n){
        this.num = n;
    }
}


public class SinglyCircularList {

    private static NodeS head = null;
    private static NodeS tail = null;
    private static int size = 0;

    public static int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public static void insert(int n) {
        NodeS node = new NodeS(n);
        node.next = tail;
        if (tail == null) {
            tail = node;
        } else {
            head.next = node;
        }
        head = node;
        size++;
    }

    public static int delete() {
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            NodeS deq = tail;
            tail = deq.next;
            size--;
            if (size == 0) {
                tail = null;
            }
            head.next = tail;
            return deq.num;
        } else {
            System.out.println("List Empty !!");
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    public void printList() {
        NodeS temp = tail;
        for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
            if (temp != null) {
                System.out.print(temp.num);
                temp = temp.next;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SinglyCircularList scl = new SinglyCircularList();
        scl.insert(1);
        scl.insert(2);
        scl.insert(3);
        scl.insert(4);
        scl.insert(5);
        scl.insert(6);
        scl.insert(7);
        scl.printList();
        System.out.println("Del->" + scl.delete());
        scl.insert(8);
        scl.printList();
        System.out.println("Del->" + scl.delete());
        System.out.println("Del->" + scl.delete());
        System.out.println("Del->" + scl.delete());
        System.out.println("Del->" + scl.delete());
        System.out.println("Del->" + scl.delete());
        System.out.println("Del->" + scl.delete());
        System.out.println("Del->" + scl.delete());
        System.out.println("Del->" + scl.delete());
        scl.printList();
        scl.insert(9);
        scl.insert(10);
        scl.printList();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

I have only a couple of points:

**1**

You implementation will be able to store only one list throughout your Java program:

```
SinglyCircularList list1 = new SinglyCircularList();
SinglyCircularList list2 = new SinglyCircularList();

list1.insert(1); // Here list1 = [1], and list2 = [1];
list2.insert(2); // Now  list1 = [1, 2], and list2 = [1, 2]
```

So, basically, you should remove the keyword **`static`** from **everywhere** except the **`main(String[] args)`**.

**2**

It would be nicer if your **`delete`** method would throw an exception on deleting from an empty list.

**3**

Instead of **`printList()`** you could override the **`public String toString()`**.

**4**

```
private static NodeS head = null;
private static NodeS tail = null;
private static int size = 0;
```

Whenever declaring class or object fields, references are initialized **by default** with **`null`**, and numeric fields to zero. You can write simply:

```
private NodeS head;
private NodeS tail;
private int size;
```

**Summa summarum**

I had something like that in mind:

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class SinglyCircularList<E> {

    private static final class Node<E> {

        private final E datum;
        private Node<E> next;

        Node(final E datum) {
            this.datum = datum;
        }

        E getDatum() {
            return datum;
        }   

        Node<E> getNext() {
            return next;
        }

        void setNext(final Node<E> next) {
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    private Node<E> head;
    private Node<E> tail;
    private int size;

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    public void insert(final E datum) {
        final Node<E> newnode = new Node<>(datum);

        if (head == null) {
            head = newnode;
            tail = newnode;
            size = 1;
            return;
        }

        tail.setNext(newnode);
        tail = newnode;
        size++;
    }

    public E delete() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Deleting from an empty list.");
        }

        final E ret = head.getDatum();

        if (size == 1) {
            head = null;
            tail = null;
        } else {
            head = head.getNext();
            tail.setNext(head);
        }

        size--;
        return ret;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[");

        if (size > 0) {
            sb.append(head.getDatum());
        } else {
            return "[]";
        }

        Node<E> currentNode = head.getNext();

        for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i, currentNode = currentNode.getNext()) {
            sb.append(", ").append(currentNode.getDatum());
        }

        return sb.append("]").toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SinglyCircularList<Integer> scl = new SinglyCircularList<>();

        System.out.println("Creating the list:");

        for (int i = 1; i <= 8; ++i) {
            System.out.println(scl);
            scl.insert(i);
        }

        System.out.println(scl);

        System.out.println("Removing from the list:");

        while (!scl.isEmpty()) {
            scl.delete();
            System.out.println(scl);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

#### Tail unnecessary

Your `tail` pointer is always the same as `head.next`, so you really don't need to track it.  All of your functions would simplify a bit.  Your insertion function would become:

```
public static void insert(int n)
{
    NodeS node = new NodeS(n);

    if (head == null) {
        node.next = node;
    } else {
        node.next = head.next;
        head.next = node;
    }
    head = node;
    size++;
}
```

Your deletion function would become:

```
public static int delete()
{
    if (isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("List Empty !!");
        return -1;
    }

    NodeS deq = head.next;
    head.next = (--size == 0) ? null : deq.next;
    return deq.num;
}
```

Lastly, in `printList()`, you would replace `tail` with `head.next`.

Comment: (Was going to comment the first observation looked swapped when [dfhwze's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/225606/93149) alerted me to the peculiarity in the code presented for review.)

Answer (score 1):

#### Terminology flawed

You have also swapped the `head` and `tail`. The first element is the head, the last the tail.

---

#### Bug on insert

Your code is bugged. A single item gets printed fine:

> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>     SinglyCircularList scl = new SinglyCircularList();
>     scl.insert(1);
>     scl.printList();    // 1
> }
> ```

But adding more items yields in the first added item being duplicated at the back:

> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>     SinglyCircularList scl = new SinglyCircularList();
>     scl.insert(1);
>     scl.insert(2);
>     scl.printList();    // 121 instead of 12
> }
> ```

---

#### Specification not met

And most importantly, **your list is not circular**. A circular list has the property that it nevers yields `null` on calling any `node.next`. But as you can see in your `print` method, you reach null.

> ```
> public void printList() {
>     NodeS temp = tail;
>     for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
>         if (temp != null) {
>             System.out.print(temp.num);
>             temp = temp.next;
>         }
>     }
>     System.out.println();
> }
> ```

---

### Refactored to Circular Linked List

To make the list circular, we only need to track the `head`. The tail is the last `next` that is not the `head`, unless we have a single element.

```
private NodeS head = null;
private int size = 0;

public NodeS getTail() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    NodeS node = head;
    do {
        node = node.next;
    } while (node != head);
    return node;
}
```

Inserting an element at the tail should be called `append`. Here's a circular implemenation:

```
 public void append(int n) {
    NodeS node = new NodeS(n);
    if (isEmpty()) {
        head = node;
        head.next = head;
    } else {
        NodeS tail = getTail();
        tail.next = node;
        node.next = head;
    }
    size++;
}
```

Removing at the head should be called `poll`. Here's a circular implementation:

```
public int poll() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return -1;
    }
    int num = head.num;
    head = head.next;
    size--;
    if (isEmpty()) {
        head = null;
    } else {
        NodeS tail = getTail();
        tail.next = head;
    }
    return num;
}
```

And printing the list should be from head to tail and also circular:

```
public void printList() {
     NodeS node = head;
     if (node == null) {
         System.out.println("Empty List");
         return;
     }
     do {
         System.out.print(node.num);
         node = node.next;
     } while (node != head);
     System.out.println();
}
```

#### Verification

Here's an updated test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SinglyCircularList scl = new SinglyCircularList();
    scl.printList();
    scl.append(1);
    scl.printList();
    scl.append(2);
    scl.printList();
    System.out.println(scl.poll() + " removed");
    scl.printList();
    System.out.println(scl.poll() + " removed");
    scl.printList();
}
```

yielding:

> ```
> Empty List
> 1
> 12
> 1 removed
> 2
> 2 removed
> Empty List
> ```